# Why is SegWit disabled and old address gone when recovering an Armory paper wallet?

Tags: address, wallet-recovery, armory, multi-signature

I wanted to make absolutely sure I could recover my Armory wallet with M of N recovery keys. So instead of doing just a test, I deleted the wallet and restored it. But now Segwit for getting receiving address is disabled
[image: Segwit disabled]
And my old receive address isn't showing.
I'm using the Goatpig fork of Armory, version 0.96.3.99-beta since it's the only one which properly created M-of-N keys in the GUI rather than command line.
Will I still be able to receive BTC in this wallet with my old Segwit receive address even though I can't make any new ones?